# Configuring outlook working-hours with powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

In my company where we use AD infrastructure my working hours in outlook somehow change from working hours and my time-zone. I created a script that changes the time-zone, but don't know how to change the working hours in outlook.

QUESTIONS:

- searching for POWER-SHELL OUTLOOK API gave no results - wanted to ask how to approach scripting the outlook application (or any other application) with powershell? What is the development process step-by-step? Is there an API defined for each application for powershell?
- How does powershell interact with applications? Is there a general command-object infrastructure for all windows applications that powershell accesses?
- And for the specific question: how to actually change the working hours in OUTLOOK?

Thank you?

Answer (score 1):

Powershell can use any IDispatch-based libraries, including the Outlook Object Model. But OOM however does not provide any way to set those options. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), you can use its [RDOCalendarOptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdocalendaroptions.htm) object - next version of Redemption will expose R`DOCalendarOptions.WorkDays/WorkDayStart`/etc. properties.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. Could you also addres any of the other questions so that I couls accept the answer?

Comment: I know next to nothing about PowerShell, but I can answer Outlook related questions.